# How to prevent JDialog from popping up in front of the JFrame when I close the JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

### Code Explanation:

I have a `class` named `GUI` which `extends JFrame` and have a `boolean` variable `closable` in the `class`. I added a `WindowListener` to the `JFrame` and also `setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);` to the `JFrame`. This prevents the `JFrame` from closing. Everything works as expected.

I do `GUI prog=new GUI()` from `main` in another `class` and display the `JFrame` using `prog.setVisible(true);`. I also make a `JDialog` named `d` and display it behind the `JFrame`. When `d` is closed,the `JFrame` can be closed too.

### Problem:

My code works. The only issue is that when I press the <kbd>X</kbd>(close button) in the title bar of the `JFrame` without closing the `JDialog` behind it,then the `JDialog` pops up in front of the `JFrame` when the first `JOptionPane()` executes.

### Code:

The main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;  //All these are used in my full program

public class ThirdProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      final GUI prog=new GUI("My ThirdProgram in Java"); //Creating the JFrame
      prog.setBounds(350,325,610,175);
      prog.setResizable(false);

      JDialog d=new JDialog(); //The problematic JDialog
      d.setBounds(400,400,500,70);
      d.add(new JLabel("I'm trying hard to stop you from closing the JFrame in front of you"));
      d.setTitle("Unidentified JDialog");
      d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      d.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

      d.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
          prog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //JFrame is now closable
          prog.closable=false;
        }
      });

      d.setVisible(true);
      prog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The `class` which `extends JFrame`:

```
class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

//some code here

boolean closable=true;    

public GUI(String header)
{
  setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

  addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent){
    if(closable)  /*The problem occurs when the below JOptionPane() executes*/
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You can't close this that easily! So try this program!","No way!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    else
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Eh...Where has the Guy preventing you from closing this gone?!?","Security Bypassed!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }});

 /*Lots of code after this*/
```

### Question:

How can I prevent the `JDialog` from popping in front of the `JFrame` when I close it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when you create a JDialog you specify a JFrame as the owner. This is so that when you click on the frame Icon on the task bar all the child dialogs can be displayed with the JFrame, otherwise there is no way to activate the dialog unless you minimize all other active windows on the desktop.

If you truly want an independent JDialog then you need to specify your dialog as a child of another frame:

```
//JDialog d=new JDialog(); //The problematic JDialog
JDialog d=new JDialog(new JFrame()); //The problematic JDialog
```

Comment: I just did what you said and it worked as expected. Why does the `JDialog` pop up in front of the `JFrame` though when using `JDialog d=new JDialog();`? I've never specified it to be the owner of the `JFrame`

Comment: I believe a JDialog needs a JFrame as an owner so by default there is some kind of system frame that is used. I guess somehow this is related to the frame you just created. I don't know the details of how it is implemented.